# How large could launchers become?

Tags: spacecraft-development, launch-vehicle

I've heard that the size of Saturn V was pretty much as big as could've been built in the 1960s. And the Soviet N1 did basically fail because it was too large for their infrastructure and engine size at the time. Generally, there's an economic advantage with larger scale, given enough demand for the-bigger-the-better one piece payloads, which I want us to fictionally assume here. What are the technical challenges that limit how large a chemical launcher, from the surface of Earth to orbit, could be built?

Comment: The Saturn V was as big as necessary for the moon landing. In the early 1960s some larger versions were planned under the name Nova. Saturn V used 5 F-1 engines for the first stage, there were Nova versions with 8 F-1. Nova development was cancelled 1964.

Comment: FWIW, the N1 failed in large part because the Soviets couldn't manage the coordination between lots of engines, and harmonics kept blowing things up. Modern computers and electronic controls would have little trouble.

Comment: "I've heard that the size of Saturn V was pretty much as big as could've been built in the 1960s" -- do you have a citation for that? It's true in the relatively narrow sense that the development program for a larger rocket taken on in 1961 probably wouldn't have been completed by 1970, but not due to purely technological limitations.

Comment: Why would you launch large one-piece payloads, rather than multiple loads that would be assembled in orbit?  I'd think it'd be a lot cheaper to use 20 commodity, reusable SpaceX launchers than to design & build 1 rocket to lift 20X as much payload.  Plus one failure doesn't doom the entire project - you just launch another sub-assembly.

Comment: Many management costs scale less than linearly with the size of the launch, and on-orbit assembly comes with costs as well. One Sea Dragon at $2.3 billion per launch in today's money would be competitive with 20-30 Falcon 9s.

Comment: @jamesqf: dividing a large payload into 20 pieces of equal mass could be difficult. Some extra weight might be necessary to enable easy and fast assembley of the pieces in the zero g environment of a low orbit. The dry mass of one large propellant tank could be lower than an array of several smaller tanks with connecting pipes and additional structural elements.

Comment: @Uwe: Well, imagine trying to launch the ISS as a single piece :-)  Or take a practical Mars mission, which divides into many pieces - several habitat modules (since you need to spin them at the end of cables of gravity), landers, boosters for return, &c.  Or even the Apollo missions, which could have been done with 3 pieces assembled in Earth orbit.

Comment: @jamesqf *"Why would you launch large one-piece payloads, rather than multiple loads that would be assembled in orbit?"* I have no idea. Just assume it for the purpose of this question. My wife recognizes no limit for how much luggage she brings aboard an airplane, we are over-charged every time. Let's just pretend to be feminist and accept whatever demand claimed. (I'd give you her phone number if I thought you could change her mind about baggage). She has two motti: The bigger the better and put this there! (I wish NASA had those ideals!) My ex-wife, to clarify for those who take notes.

Comment: @jamesqf: It is true that the Apollo assembley could be separated into 3 parts easily, the CM, SM and LM. But the masses are very different, the CM 5840 kg, the LM 16428 kg and the SM with 24523 kg (all numbers for Apollo 15) If you have a launcher with a payload capacity for the SM, 18683 of that capacity is wasted for the CM. You forgot one essential part, the third stage of Saturn V needed for trans lunar injection. The problem is to to get parts of nearly equal weight which could be assembled easily in an orbit. From the complete LM, the decent stage could be separated. But SM was one unit

Comment: @Uwe: But I think it could have been designed to use 3 (or more) reasonably-sized pieces, and so probably launched with multiple Saturn Is.  It would seem quite a bit cheaper to 40 or so Saturn I launches, rather than spend the money needed to develop the Saturn V for a mere 13.

Comment: @jamesqf: The CM could not be assembled from several parts in orbit, the heatshield should be without joints. The SM could be assembled from  several parts, but the total weight would be increased by the necessary extra connectors. The descent stage of the LM was designed for separation, but not for assembley in orbit. The necessary modifications would increase the weight.

Comment: @Uwe: I think a 2 or 3 piece SM might have decreased total weight slightly.  With the one-piece design, you need extra fuel to decelerate into lunar orbit, and boost the larger empty tankage back out.  But I'm not going to do detailed engineering calculations :-)

Answer (score 13):

SpaceX is proposing launch vehicle, as a first stage, and a second stage that would transit to Mars.  Interplanetary Space Transport (ITS).

The final size is not really confirmed, and they should actually build it before we compare it, but using chemical rockets, it is quite a bit larger than a Saturn V.

[image: SpaceX ITS booster]

The Saturn V used 5 F-1 engines with around 1.5 million lbs of thrust. The ITS first stage is planned to use 42 (!!!!) Raptor engines for a total of 29 million lbs of thrust.

Clearly larger than a Saturn V is in the realm of possible.

Large engines are hard, as the F-1 engine development showed, and as the Soviet experience that lead to 30 NK-15/NK-33 engines for the N-1 showed.

SpaceX has taken a middle of the road approach, but closer to the N-1 approach with fairly large numbers of medium sized engines.

Moving the booster around is quite tricky. NASA solved it by barging the large components. US Rail does not support such large objects. Soviet rail seems like it was able to handle larger as most of their components were moved by rail.

SpaceX plans to solve it by flying the vehicle around. (Or at least manufacturing near the launch site, and after that, land and relaunch mostly in place).

Comment: ITS is only slightly taller and fatter than Saturn V, still it can (hopefully) launch so many more times payload to orbit? I'm sure there's plenty of speculations about that around, but in principle, don't launchers with chemical engines need to be larger in proportion to their capabilities?

Comment: Methane/LOX vs RP-1/LOX so fairly higher Isp even on first stage. Quite a bit bulkier. And even then, for Mars missions need 5 refuelling launches for the upper stage.

Comment: The relative visual sizes are deceptive; the Saturn V 2nd and 3rd stages are full of hydrolox, with a bulk density of about 0.36, while the ITS methalox propellant has a density of about 0.8 -- it's thus a much more massive launcher.

Comment: Also, the side-by side images may be misleading.  Remember that volume goes up as the square of the diameter.

Answer (score 7):

It's generally thought that the Sea Dragon design was technically feasible; this would be 18000 tons (6 times the mass of Saturn V) at liftoff and deliver 500 tons to LEO, comparable to the SpaceX ITS in expendable mode. Mass fraction and specific impulse would be worse than Saturn V but economy of scale would make it more cost effective per payload ton. It was never produced because the demand for such large payloads never arose, of course.

I don't know of any specific hard technical limitation to going bigger than Sea Dragon, though mass fraction probably gets poorer and logistic issues get hairier as you embiggen.

http://www.astronautix.com/s/seadragon.html

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Dragon_(rocket)

Comment: For the record: ITS was said to have a capacity of 550 tons (possibly short tons, which would be about 500 metric) to LEO if used in expendable configuration. Since Sea Dragon wasn't supposed to be reusable, that's a fairer comparison...

Comment: Good catch, will edit.

Comment: Although Sea Dragon was supposed to be partially reusable with parachute recovery of first stage.

Comment: @RussellBorogove that is somewhat unlikely to have worked out. Parachutes don't scale well to the sort of size that would be necessary for the Sea Dragon first stage.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, it's not exactly parachute. The stage would be largely a big empty tank, with consequently low terminal velocity, and an inflatable drag flare further reduces impact velocity to a "mere" 90 m/sec. 55 tons of structure is allocated to the flare and recovery equipment, and another 20 tons of structural reinforcement relative to the expendable version.

Answer (score 3):

Engines haven't changed much, so most improvements to size would likely come from the use of lightweight composite materials. The performance of these isn't as much better than aluminum alloys as is sometimes imagined though, so I doubt that would improve the situation a whole lot.

Nuclear thermal launch would improve payload fractions. The ability to use purely hydrogen propellant alone would dramatically improve exhaust velocity and thus the payload fraction of the rocket. This is essentially the only benefit, as in all such cases the temperatures and pressures are limited by the properties of chamber materials. It's quite a benefit though. The logarithmic term in the rocket equation makes high exhaust velocity extremely desirable. The key capability tradeoffs of course come from the high cost of nuclear systems and safety issues. It is worth noting though that no practical research has been in this area for several decades, so it's not clear what thrust to weight ratios could be achieved today.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Comment: But how is the payload fraction a limit for launcher size? I edited my question to remove the distraction of nuclear propulsion, that was a side track, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The major technical challenges of up-sizing rocket boosters, as I see it, are in two major categories: weight, and risk mitigation.

#### Weight

The most profitable business is weight reduction. There is money to be made on developing future materials (metals, and fuels) and structural design. These areas are relevant because the rate at which the size of the spacecraft increases, currently, will match and overtake the power efficiency very fast. Which is why we see the SpaceX Interplanetary Transportation System as three smaller craft taped together for added boosters.

#### Risk mitigation

Therefore the best thing for weight, multiple layered systems, is also the best thing for mitigation of risk for these "glorified explosions". Realize that not only are you controlling an explosion to propel these things into space, you are also preventing a fuel supply from igniting mid-trajectory. This is a very expensive cargo to be taking from point A to point B, and having a lesser amount of fuel mid-flight and capital loss to control is always prevalent.